# How can I use specific yarn version?

Tags: node.js, docker, yarnpkg, yarn-v2

I have a configuration in my local environment working successfully. For instance, I have the following versions:

yarn -  3.2.4

node - 14.8.0

npm -  6.14.0

These versions are working fine in my local environment, I am able to start the React application, everything is good. However, when passing this configuration to my docker file is when I have issues. I included the following:

```
FROM node:14.8

RUN yarn set version 3.2.4
RUN yarn --version
```

In package.json I added the following line at the end:

```
"packageManager": "yarn@3.2.4"
```

When building the DockerFile I am getting the following:

> [3/10] RUN yarn set version 3.2.4:
> #8 1.212 Resolving 3.2.4 to a url...
> #8 2.398 error An unexpected error occurred: "Release not found: 3.2.4".
> #8 2.398 info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/yarn-error.log".
> #8 2.398 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/policies for documentation about this command.

---

executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn set version 3.2.4]: exit code: 1

I am not able to change the version of node due to a dependency with "node-sass": "4.14.1" which requires node 14

I am able to set the version of yarn in my local using node 14.8, but when executing in the Dockerfile is not finding the yarn version 3.2.4.

Do you know how can I enforce the installation of yarn 3.2.4 in Docker with the node 14?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `yarn set version [version]`
Refer: https://yarnpkg.com/cli/set/version